# Template Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, template, binary-search

This is a simple binary search tree implementation written with C++'s templates feature I wrote to learn C++. What improvements would make this cleaner and better as far as C++ practices go, and are there any problems with implementing the algorithm?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


template <class T, class V>
class BinarySearchTree {

    struct t_node {
        t_node * parent;
        t_node * left;
        t_node * right;

        T data;
        V value;
        // Sorted by Value
    };

    t_node * root;

    t_node* getMin() {
        return getMin(root);
    }
    t_node* getMin(t_node * x) {
        while (x->left !=nullptr) {
            x = x->left;
        }
        return x;
    }

    t_node* getMax() {
        t_node * x = root;
        while (x->right != nullptr) {
            x = x->right;
        }
        return x;
    }

    t_node* sucessor(t_node* x) {
        if (x->right != nullptr) {
            return getMin(x->right);
        }
        t_node * y = x->parent;
        while (y!=nullptr && x==y->right) {
            x = y;
            y = y->parent;
        }
        return y;
    }

public:

    void inOrderTreeWalk() {
        inOrderTreeWalk(root);
    }

    // Needs Stream Overload on template T type to work.
    void inOrderTreeWalk(t_node * x) {
        if (x != nullptr) {
            inOrderTreeWalk(x->left);
            cout << x->data;
            inOrderTreeWalk(x->right);
        }
    }

    T search(V keyword) {
        t_node * x = root;
        while (x!=nullptr && keyword != x->value) {
            if (keyword < x->value) {
                x = x->left;
            }
            else x = x->right;
        }
        return x->data;
    }

    void insert(V keyword, T object) {
        // Create t_node;
        t_node * z = new t_node;
        z->value = keyword;
        z->data = object;


        t_node * y = nullptr;
        t_node * x = root;

        while (x!= nullptr) {
            y = x;
            if (z->value < x->value) {
                x = x->left;
            }
            else x = x->right;
        }
        z->parent = y;
        if (y == nullptr) {
            root = z;
        } else if (z->value < y->value) {
            y->left = z;
        } else y->right = z;
    }
};


// Demo Code
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {


    string Charles = "Charles Finny";
    string CharlesD = "Personal Assistant";
    string Bob = "Bob of Yorkshire";
    string BobD = "Unkown";
    string Sam = "Sam Smith";
    string SamD = "Programmer";
    string Mary = "Mary Jane";
    string MaryD = "Manager";

    BinarySearchTree<string, string> EmployeeRecords;
    EmployeeRecords.insert(Charles, CharlesD);
    EmployeeRecords.insert(Bob, BobD);
    EmployeeRecords.insert(Sam, SamD);
    EmployeeRecords.insert(Mary, MaryD);

    string result = EmployeeRecords.search("Sam Smith");
    cout << result << "\n" ;
    EmployeeRecords.inOrderTreeWalk();



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One obvious problem is that your implementation leaks memory. You should better use `std::unique_ptr<t_node>` instead of the raw pointers `t_node*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to the suggestions made by Barry [in his answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/112758/37893).

**Add constructors to `t_node`**

They make sure that all the member variables are initialized properly.

```
struct t_node {

   // Default constructor
   t_node () : parent(nullptr), left(nullptr), right(nullptr), data(), value() {}

   // Constructor with data.
   t_node (T d, V v) : parent(nullptr), left(nullptr), right(nullptr), data(d), value(v) {}

    t_node * parent;
    t_node * left;
    t_node * right;

    T data;
    V value;
    // Sorted by Value
};
```

**Add default constructor, copy constructor, and copy assignment operator**

See [The Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) for issues that need to be dealt with when your class uses dynamic memory allocation.

With your posted code, the member variable `root` remains uninitialized when you construct an instance of `BinarySearchTree`. In theory, your code is subject to undefined behavior. With a default constructor, you can make sure that `root` is initialized properly -- most likely to `nullptr`.

**`getMin()` has the potential to access `nullptr`**

You have:

```
t_node* getMin() {
    return getMin(root);
}
t_node* getMin(t_node * x) {
    while (x->left !=nullptr) {
        x = x->left;
    }
    return x;
}
```

When the object is empty and `root` is initialized to `nullptr`, you will end up accessing `x->left` with value of `x` being `nullptr`. That is cause for undefined behavior.

I suggest

```
t_node* getMin() {
    if (root)
       return getMin(root);
    else
       return nullptr;
}
```

**Make `getMax()` similar to `getMin()`**

Add

```
t_node* getMax() {
    if (root)
       return getMax(root);
    else
       return nullptr;
}
```

**Do not pollute your class with `cout`**

Change `inOrderTreeWalk` to take a functor as an argument. Call the functor for every item of the `BinarySearchTree`.

```
template <typename F>
void inOrderTreeWalk(F f) {
    inOrderTreeWalk(root, f);
}

template <typename F>
void inOrderTreeWalk(t_node * x, F f) {
    if (x != nullptr) {
        inOrderTreeWalk(x->left, f);
        f(x->data);
        inOrderTreeWalk(x->right, f);
    }
}
```

And now, you can use it as:

```
EmployeeRecords.inOrderTreeWalk([](std::string const& s) { std::cout << s << std::endl;} );
```

Comment: Great! When calling `inOrderTreeWalk`, why do we need the '[ ]` syntax before defining the constant string?

Comment: That's the syntax for defining  a lambda function. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda for further details.

Answer (score 4):

**Memory Handling**

I see `new` but I don't see `delete`. Your tree leaks memory. It needs to clean up after itself in a destructor. And once you add that, you get into the [Rule of Three](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three): you need to add the copy constructor and the copy assignment operator, otherwise you'd still leak when you copy your tree.

**Usage**

Your code looks like an implementation of `std::map`, and your usage suggests the same, so it'd be better to change your template arguments from `T` and `V` (which mean nothing) to `Key` and `Value`. Using `value` as the key is confusing - you should name it `key`. Although conventionally nodes for maps in the C++ standard library use `std::pair<const Key, Value>`s.

You should make it clear that `Key` needs to be both LessThanComparable and EqualityComparable, or provide ways of passing comparators in as template arguments.

If I try to `search()` for something not in the map, `x` will eventually become `nullptr` and then you return `x->data`. Oops!

You can insert elements with duplicate `value`s. Is that intentional?

`inOrderTreeWalk` should be spelled `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const BinarySearchTree &)`.

**Other**

1. Avoid `using namespace std;`, **especially** in headers.
2. Take your arguments by reference to const to avoid having to deal with copies.
3. You should support erasing elements.
4. You should look into various balancing algorithms for you tree so that if I insert 1 then 2 then 3 then 4 then 5, I don't end up with linear-time search.
5. `return 0;` from `main()` is implied, you don't need to explicitly provide it.